# Change text color according to the banckground color

Tags: javascript

I have a function that randomly change page background color and also the text with the same color. The problem: when the background is white, the text is also white. To solve this I want to create a function that will change the text to black when the background is white.

```
function changetitlecolor() {   
if (document.body.style.backgroundColor= "#ffffff"){ 

document.getElementById("title").style.color="#000000"; 

document.getElementById("message").style.color="#000000"; 
} 
 }
```

The above code is indeed changing the text color but it's also changing the page background to white and I don't want this to happen.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: @j08691 Oh, didn't notice this. So simple. Thank you.